# How can I put a Mac OS X .app under version control as one file?

Tags: macos, git

I am quite new to Git; I use SourceTree on Mac OS X.

When I start tracking an `.app` file, Git treats it as multiple files inside the `.app` content.

Is there any way to make another Git client only get that `.app` file as an application package rather than as multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.app .framework .bundle .pages and more, everyone of these is application package, a directory/folder in your disk.

Either svn or git seen that as directory, because they should support windows/linux. Maybe some git client would shown application package as a "file", but I think shown as directory is better.

Another way store .app as a file is zip it and upload to git, it would be clean.

Answer (score 2):

These `.app` things are not files; they're *directories*. To convince yourself of this, try running

```
ls -la /Applications/
```

and note the `d` at the beginning of the permission flags corresponding to `*.app` entries:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 App Store.app
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 Automator.app
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 Calculator.app
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 Calendar.app
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 Chess.app
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root          wheel    102 31 Jan 16:32 Contacts.app
...
```

As long as Unix sees those as directories, so will Git. If you want Git to treat a `*.app` as a single file, you'll have to archive its contents in some fashion or another.